# Insert Operations in STL Class Templates

Tags: c++

I have a test coming up, and it appears that some of the questions involve STL class template functions. Many deal with algorithm complexity, so I trying get the complexity of basic operations down. One that I find confusing is the insert operation. The insert operation takes a given container allows inserts to be made starting from some position pointed at by an iterator:

```
vector<int> vector1;

for (int i=1; i<6; i++) vector1.push_back(i);

vector<int>::iterator it;

it = vector1.begin();

vector1.insert(it+2,10);
```

Now, I recognize that this the insert operation will take linear time for most insert operations. However, if I was to insert a single item, would this still take linear time? I ask this because for the list STL, inserting a single item takes constant time. I figured that this was because list is a dynamic double linked circular chain.

The vector is a dynamic, contiguous storage structure, so does this mean that for any insert before vector[size-1], all items after the insert will have to be moved up by one unit?

Now, for the deque. I am thinking of the deque STL as a system of singly linked chains pointed at by pointers in an array; is this correct? If this is the case, would a single insert into a deque, not at the front or back, be O(1)?

Thanks, sorry for so many questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some notes:

- As you suggest, an insert into a `std::list` takes `O(1)` time.
- As you suggest, an insert into a `std::vector` will need to move all remaining elements of the vector one space back, which takes `O(n)` time.
- The standard does not require a specific implementation of deques, but it does require that inserts into the front and back take `O(1)` time.
- However, deques do **not** require `O(1)` insertion time if you insert into the middle of the container.
- As an aside, vectors only provide `O(1)` insertion time if you insert at the end of the container.
- [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) gives a comment about what it feels is a frequent implementation method for deques. It says that the common implementation is a series of fixed length of arrays. So we have arrays that can store, say 16 elements, and we have a `std::list` (more or less) of those arrays.
- <strike>As far as I know, an implementation **could** implement `std::deque` identically to `sd::list`. However, there are performance improvements that could be had by not doing this. **If** a particular implementation did this, then inserts in the middle of a deque would be O(1). However, this is not required.</strike>
- A `std::deque` can not be implemented as a `std::list` because it provides a random access iterator. This means that `deque::at(4)` needs to provide that iterator in constant time. A `std::list` can not do that.

---

In regards to the comment about why the generic `deque::insert` would be `O(n)`, here's my thoughts. Let's assume we use cppreference's implementation of a deque.

Let's create a deque, with 10 elements. Inserted one after another. We'll assume, that the deque is implemented by arrays of 4 elements.

So, the deque currently, is implemented as:

```
[ E, E, E, E ] <-> [ E, E, E, E ] <-> [ E, E, _, _ ]
```

Let's insert an element at the back.

```
[ E, E, E, E ] <-> [ E, E, E, E ] <-> [ E, E, E, _ ]
```

Let's insert an element at the front

```
[ _, _, _, E] <-> [ E, E, E, E ] <-> [ E, E, E, E ] <-> [ E, E, E, _ ]
```

All of those operations make sense how they could work as O(1).

What if we inserted an element at the middle of the array.

```
[ _, _, _, E] <-> [ E, E, E, E ] <-> [ E, E, E, E ] <-> [ E, E, E, _ ]
                                      ^ I want to insert here!
```

To do that, I'll need to shift 7 elements out of the way. This is why this operation is likely `O(n)`.

Comment: If the deque insertion was O(N), would this be a result of iterating through a sequence of elements to reach the point of insertion?

Comment: @Jonnywalkerr: My response to this is quite long, so it's in the answer rather than in the comment box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a single item into a vector, it would still take linear time because of the reason that you mentioned.

The deque implementation is specific to the implementer.  However, insertion into positions not at the front or back are most likely linear time (not constant time).